# Rails - Shorten "Tuesday" into "T"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this string: <%= deal.tuesday%> in my show.html. On my website it appears as "Tuesday". Is there any way I could make change it to "T" from my show.html page?

I dont want to change my controller or anything, I just want to use something like truncate that will allow my to change it just for the view page. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `tuesday`returns a String you can just do it like so

```
<%= deal.tuesday[0] %>
```

Comment: Note that this will return "T" for Tuesday and Thursday, and "S" for Saturday and Sunday. If you need more specific abbreviations, `deal.tuesday.first(2)` will return "Tu" or "Th," or "Sa" or "Su."